# change stroke dynamically -vuejs

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to change stroke attribute color dynamically, I tried using binding like `:stroke="CTAColor"`, but it didn't work.

Here's a simple SVG **:**

```
<svg class="swiper-arrow" viewBox="0 0 44 45" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" v-if="language ==='en'" >
     <rect x="-0.5" y="0.5" width="43" height="43" rx="21.5" transform="matrix(-1 0 0 1 42.999 0.250366)" stroke="#05AA9F"/>
     <path d="M25.499 17.7504L29.999 22.2504M29.999 22.2504L25.499 26.7504M29.999 22.2504H13.999" stroke="#05AA9F" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What's the value of `CTAColor`?

Comment: There is no reason for binding like this to not work, so there must be an issue with the value provided

Comment: @mohamed #05AA9F

Comment: @LK77 yes you're right , it was an object